# Trouble with Const Pointers

Tags: c++, pointers, parameter-passing

I'm trying to use the function:

```
bool pcl::visualization::PCLVisualizer::addPointCloud(const pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ >::ConstPtr & cloud,
const std::string &     id = "cloud",
int     viewport = 0     
)
```

So I have the following code as global variables:

```
pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ> linaccpc;
const pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ> * linptr = &linaccpc;
boost::shared_ptr<pcl::visualization::PCLVisualizer> linplotter (new pcl::visualization::PCLVisualizer("linear acceleration");
```

And then in my main function:

```
linplotter->addPointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ> (linptr, "linear acc", 0);
```

And I get the error:

```
error: no matching function for call to 'pcl::visualization::PCLVisualizer::addPointCloud(const pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ>*&, const char [11], int)'
linplotter->addPointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ> (linptr, "linear acc", 0);
                                                                 ^
```

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: read this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/57483/what-are-the-differences-between-a-pointer-variable-and-a-reference-variable-in

Comment: Is too hard to make a minimal example?

Comment: http://pointclouds.org/documentation/tutorials/pcl_visualizer.php I've been using this to help me. I also tried declaring the pointer as `pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ>::ConstPtr linptr = linaccpc;` but getting an error with conversion from 'pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ>' to non-scalar type 'pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ>::ConstPtr {aka boost::shared_ptr<const pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ> >}' requested

Comment: Thanks KS, however this thing requires boost, which I am not in a mood to  download now. I mean that you could make a minimal example with the same case of const pointers. That way it would be super easy to help you, at least in my case. :)

Comment: @gsamaras If you have a C++11 compiler you may use `std::shared_ptr` which is very similar to what `boost::shared_ptr` was

Comment: @MattMcNabb: That assumes PCL will accept `std::shared_ptr` and not rely solely on `boost::shared_ptr` only.

Comment: @MattMcNabb yes, but I am not the one seeking for help here. I really feel that a minimal example would be sweet here. But Remy felt generous.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Look at the definition of `addPointCloud()` more carefully:

```
bool pcl::visualization::PCLVisualizer::addPointCloud(
    const pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ >::ConstPtr & cloud,
    const std::string &     id = "cloud",
    int     viewport = 0     
)
```

Its first parameter is a `const` reference to a `pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ>::ConstPtr`, where `ConstPtr` is a typedef for `boost::shared_ptr<const PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ>>`.

You are trying to pass a `pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ>*` where a `boost::shared_ptr<const PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ>>` is expected.  That does not match the definition.

`boost::shared_ptr` has an `explicit` constructor for single-value input, so the compiler cannot implicitly create a temporary `boost::shared_ptr<const PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ>>` for your `pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ>*` value.

To get around that, you will have to invoke the explicit constructor directly:

```
pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ> linaccpc;
const pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ> *linptr = &linaccpc;
...
linplotter->addPointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ> (pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ>::ConstPtr(linptr), "linear acc", 0);
```

Or:

```
pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ> linaccpc;
pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ>::ConstPtr linptr (&linaccpc);
...
linplotter->addPointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ> (linptr, "linear acc", 0);
```

Note, however, that this will likely crash your code.  By default, `shared_ptr` calls `delete` on any pointer you give it, so it will be calling `delete` on a memory address it has no business freeing.  So allocate the pointer using `new` instead:

```
pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ>::ConstPtr linptr (new pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ>);
...
linplotter->addPointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ> (linptr, "linear acc", 0);
```

If you want to get around that and a variable whose lifetime you control, but that `shared_ptr` simply holds a pointer to, you will have to provide a custom `deleter` that will not free the variable memory when the `shared_ptr` is done using the pointer:

```
template <class T>
static void DoNotFree(T*)
{
}

...

pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ> linaccpc;
pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ>::ConstPtr linptr (&linaccpc, &DoNotFree<pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ>>);
...
linplotter->addPointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ> (linptr, "linear acc", 0);
```

This last approach will only work if `linplotter` does not need to keep using the `linaccpc` variable after it goes out of scope, such as if `linplotter` is destroyed before `lineaccpc`.  This is not something you should rely on, though.  The primary purpose of `shared_ptr` is to manage an object's lifetime for you, so let it do its job.  Use `new`.

Comment: `pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ>::ConstPtr linptr (&linaccpc);` will not be correct because the `shared_ptr` destructor will try to `delete &linaccpc`.  (You show the correct technique on the next code snippet but since OP is new to smart pointers I think it would be good to clearly say "don't do this", and also reiterate that he needs to get rid of `linaccpc` and only use the smart pointer `linptr`)

Comment: Re. your edit: `linaccpc` is a global variable in OP's code, not a stack variable.

Comment: @MattMcNabb: Stack or global, the same risk applies. But I have re-worded my answer.

Comment: So if I allocate the pointer using new, how would I point that to linaccpc, which is my point cloud object? I tried `linptr = &linaccpc;` on the next line, and I get `error: 'linptr' does not name a type`. Thank you everyone for all your help!

Comment: If you allocate a `PointCloud` using `new`, it is already its own variable in memory, you would not need a separate `lineaccpc variable at all, you would get rid of that variable from your code. Please see the examples I showed in my answer.